# After uninstalling WiX 3.11 and downgrading to 3.9, one project still wants 3.11

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017, wix, visual-studio-2019

WiX version 3.11 was installed but was uninstalled. WiX version 3.9 was then installed. During the time that 3.11 was present an empty WiX project was created. After 3.9 was installed the project was completed. At build time, an error is issued indicating that WiX version 3.11 must be installed.

We use WiX to generate installation packages. There are multiple versions of Visual Studio in use, 2013, 2017 and 2019, to accommodate various products. When WiX 3.11 was installed it was observed that VS 2013 stopped recognizing WiX projects. 3.11 was uninstalled and 3.9 re-installed. Previously existing WiX projects were again recognized and could be built by VS 2013 but the one WiX project that had been created in VS 2017 while 3.11 was in effect is still insisting on having 3.11 installed at build time. I've looked at the WiX project file and don't see why it is insisting on having 3.11 present. Does anyone know how to convince it to use the installed 3.9?

The WiX project loads in both VS 2013 and VS 2017. VS 2019 insists that the WiX project is an incompatible project type. I can live with that for now but when either VS 2013 or VS 2017 attempts to build the setup project the following error is issued:

`The WiX Toolset v3.11 (or newer) build tools must be installed to build this project. To download the WiX Toolset, see http://wixtoolset.org/releases/`

Answer (score 1):

Other respondents suggested restarting VS and rebooting. This did not fix the question. I copied the the project to a safe location and then deleted the original from the solution, TFS and disk. A new WiX was created and the previous Product.wxs file's contents were copied into the newer project's. It built and thus the problem was addressed using the time honored tradition of burning it down to the waterline and starting all over. I would much have preferred to have discovered the offending data within the original project file that was telling the system to utilize 3.11 but that, obviously, didn't happen. Maybe next time.

Comment: Yes, this general purpose solution I have also used to make individual WiX projects ([WiX source code](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3)) compile with never versions of Visual Studio than they were intended to be compiled with. It generally works better than to try to update the old project. The other common alternative is to generate a new project, zip a backup off it (so you can revert) and then migrate one setting at a time using file diff tools (for example Beyond Compare) as described in my other answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has something to do with the fact that it was created under 3.11. This means the code for 3.11 is not compatible with 3.9. If this is the case, you might just want to delete the project (not the solution), and start over with the 3.9 framework.

It might also have something to do with the Extension that is added to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

***.wixproj***: I would open the Visual Studio project file: **`Name.wixproj`** and check the content. I see sections indicating checks for version in there, but I am not up to speed 100% with what each section mean and how to fix this specific issue. It is probably well known and solved on discussion forums somewhere.

***File Diff***: One ad-hoc solution would be to create a new project with **`WiX 3.9`** and then use a file compare tool such as [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php?zz=gallery) to migrate whatever settings you actually need from the old project (WiX 3.11 format). You should be able to do this with the project open in Visual Studio. It will prompt to reload, do so and test build? Then iterate until you have a heartbeat with all settings migrated?